# Affine flatness: Why must mixed derivatives be equal?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

In the book ***Introducing Einstein's Relativity*** by Ray d'Inverno, at page 79, the author gets to the following equation:
$$\nabla_cX^a=\partial_cX^a+\Gamma^a_{bc}X^b=0,$$
where $X^a$ is a vector field e $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ is the affine connection.

Then, the book says that the solution has to have the partial derivatives commuting, that is $\partial_d\partial_cX^a=\partial_c\partial_dX^a$. How do I derive this necessary condition from the equation?

Comment: Use that: $\partial_d \partial_c X^a + \partial_d (\Gamma^a_{bc}X^b) = \partial_c \partial_d X^a + \partial_c (\Gamma^a_{bd} X^b) = 0$

Comment: I tried it and expanded the second terms of both members. I just can't figure out how to cancel them. I am sure it's silly but I'm stuck.

Comment: Some comments regarding this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/378810/149907

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be a bit stupid, but here goes:
The partial derivatives must commute in both Minkowski and Euclidean space by definition. As the partial derivatives are defined for these spaces and as the behavior of the manifold must locally reduce to Minkowski space, the partial derivatives must commute here as well.
Alternatively, one might be able to note that they commute by definition of the partial derivative (see any Calculus text and observe that, when using a partial, the coordinates are treated as independent). However, while this may allow explanation of why the constraint is needed, it does not require the use of the geodesic equation... Do you have to use the geodesic equation?

Comment: There's nothing stupid about this answer, in fact, it is the correct answer. Partial derivatives commute for twice-differentiable functions, it is a lemma from standard calculus and not specific to General Relativity at all.

Comment: I like this answer and agree 100% with it. My only doubt was about why the author said that as a consequence of the equation for a parallelly-transported vector. Thank you for your answer!